# python service cannot return int32[]

Tags: ros, python, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to create a package (in Python) which contains a service that returns int32[] named 'ids'. Unfortunately it throws two exceptions in two scenarios:

1. The Python's list contains 1 item. The exception:
   "NameError: global name '_x' is not
   defined:
2. The Python's list contains
   more than 1 item. The exception: "Invalid number of
   arguments, args should be ['ids']
   args are(1, 2)"

Please help!

FindItems.srv:

```
string type
string xml_data
---
int32[] ids
```

service:

```
import rospy
from pengo_srvs.srv import *

def on_find_items(req):
      return [1, 2, 3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node_name = "knowledge_representation"
    rospy.init_node(node_name, anonymous=True)
    service = rospy.Service("kr/find_items", FindItems, on_find_items)

    rospy.spin()
```

client:

```
import rospy, os, time
from pengo_srvs.srv import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node_name = "knowledge_representation_test"
    rospy.init_node(node_name, anonymous=True)

    service_name = "kr/find_items"
    rospy.wait_for_service(service_name)
    findItemsProxy  = rospy.ServiceProxy(service_name,  FindItems)

    nodeIDs = findItemsProxy.call("Node", "cvc")
```

Regards,
Slava

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227429/python-service-cannot-return-int32%5B%5D/) by [Slava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26053/slava/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-24**:
Please provide source code.

**Comment by [Slava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26053/slava/) on 2016-02-25**:
Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In service script you should replace `return [1,2,3]` with `return FindItemsResponse([1, 2, 3])`
You should return appropriate types.

---

Originally posted by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) with karma: 223 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Slava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26053/slava/) on 2016-02-25**:
@asagitov, thank you very much for help. I did not mention that in the documentation. Moreover I've tried to return several simple types and it worked w/o the wrapper!